# document.createTreeWalker returning duplicate elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-scraping

I'm working with the TreeWalker on Chrome to acquire the two select boxes on my html page.  My problem is the TreeWalker is returning one select element duplicated twice and the other duplicated six times.  I'm seeing element duplication with TreeWalker across many different pages, and this is my first time using TreeWalker, so I'm unsure if I implemented it incorrectly or if duplicates are a known issue that require handling.  Since html element ids are inconsistent at best, handling/catching dupes seems messy.

Below is my code:

```
const walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
let test = [];
let node;

 while ((node = walker.nextNode()) !== null) {
     let tag = (node.parentNode.tagName).toLowerCase();
     if (tag == 'select' && node.parentNode.id == 'rating') {
         test.push(node.parentNode.id)
     }
 }
 return test;
```

Returns:

> ['rating', 'rating', 'rating', 'rating', 'rating', 'rating']

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to only get unique elements?  Many thanks.

Comment: You're pushing the parent ID of the tag. So if you have one tag with four children, you'd add that ID four times.

Comment: Although, I suppose if you just want unique elements you can use a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: So I'm trying to do this generically, where I'm able to identify and filter any duplicated select box, especially those without an id property.  Thanks for the tip on sets.  This is my first time with it too, so I'll see how adding html element nodes to a set goes.